# Is there a way for a C++ function to take two different types with same members?

Tags: c++

```
struct typeA
{
  double fieldA;
}

struct typeB
{
  double fieldA;
  double fieldB;
}


void do_stuff(typeA or typeB input)
{
   input.fieldA // I will only use fieldA and will never use fieldB
}
```

It is performance sensitive so I don't want to convert it into a common type first.

Comment: Are you looking for templates?

Answer (score 9):

You can template the `do_stuff` function and the compiler will check the implementation for you. If the field isn't available you will get an error message. Here is a complete example:

```
struct typeA
{
  double fieldA;
};

struct typeB
{
  double fieldA;
  double fieldB;
};

template <typename T>
void do_stuff(T& input)
{
   input.fieldA = 10.0;
}

int main() {
    typeA a;
    do_stuff(a);

    typeB b;
    do_stuff(b);
}
```

**Note**: Remember to add the semi-colon `;` at the end of the `struct` definition (otherwise it won't compile).

Answer (score 9):

There is no performance hit if you DO use a common type, like this:

```
struct typeA
{
  double fieldA;
};

struct typeB: typeA
{
  double fieldB;
};


void do_stuff(typeA & input)
{
   input.fieldA; // I will only use fieldA and will never use fieldB
}
```

You will only start seeing performance hit once you start using virtual methods.  Unless and until you do that -- no perf costs

Answer (score 3):

You can use the template system for this:

```
 template <typename T> void do_stuff(const T& val) {
     // Use val.fieldA
 }
```

Here, if you call `do_stuff` on an object that has a field named `fieldA`, this will compile just fine and do what you want. If you try calling it on something without a `fieldA` member, this won’t compile and will report an error.

Answer (score 0):

It's funny how **the simplest solutions** will sometimes just evade us. If you "will only use fieldA and will never use fieldB" then why not:

```
void do_stuff(double& fieldA)
{
   fieldA; // I will only use fieldA and will never use fieldB
}

void test()
{
    typeA a{};
    typeB b{};

    do_stuff(a.fieldA);
    do_stuff(b.fieldA);
}
```

...